# Solving an equation without output

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, complex, timing

Could you please help in solving the equation below. I am not able to do it with the current version of mathematica (very old one). All parameters are real and positive.
Thank you so much in advance

```
sol = Solve[
   M^2 - Eps^2 + Cps (M + Eps) == 
    4 \[Alpha]^2 ((((M - Eps + Cps) b1)/(
         2 \[Alpha] q) + ((M - Eps + Cps) a)/(4 \[Alpha]^2) + 
         Hy/q (Hy/q + 1/2) - ((M - Eps + Cps) c1)/
         q^2 - ((M - Eps + Cps) c)/(4 \[Alpha]^2 q^2))/(
        2 (n + 1/2 - Sqrt[
           1/4 + Hy/q (Hy/q + 1/2) - ((M - Eps + Cps) c1)/
            q^2 - ((M - Eps + Cps) c)/(
            4 \[Alpha]^2 q^2) - ((M - Eps + Cps) a)/(4 \[Alpha]^2) + 
            Hy/2 (3/2 - 2 Subscript[H, c]) + 
            1/q (k + Subscript[H, c]) (k + Subscript[H, c] - 1)])) - (
        n + 1/2 - Sqrt[
         1/4 + Hy/q (Hy/q + 1/2) - ((M - Eps + Cps) c1)/
          q^2 - ((M - Eps + Cps) c)/(
          4 \[Alpha]^2 q^2) - ((M - Eps + Cps) a)/(4 \[Alpha]^2) + 
          Hy/2 (3/2 - 2 Subscript[H, c]) + 
          1/q (k + Subscript[H, c]) (k + Subscript[H, c] - 1)])/
        2)^2 + (M - Eps + Cps) (a + a1), Eps];
Eng[\[Alpha]_] := Eps /. sol[[1]];
Plot[Eng[\[Alpha] ], {\[Alpha], 0 , 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: The `Plot` cannot be done unless all of the parameters are given numeric values. If you assign these numeric values prior to trying to `Solve`, you will likely get a result from `Solve`

Comment: it is better to replace all those `Subscript` variables with normal variables.

Comment: You have `..stuff..+(numerator/(2*bigdenominator)+1/2*-bigdenominator)^2` and if you could look at that carefully and justify multiplying by `bigdenominator` inside that and thus get rid of that big messy `bigdenominator` or at least get it all into the numerator then that might make the problem much easier for Mathematica